# Understanding Laravel relationships better

Tags: mysql, php, many-to-many

I want to make a simple project to understand better the Laravel database relationships. So I decided to make a movie storage project which is holding some movie names and some informations about that movie, it should be look like this:

[image: capture]

So I wrote the relationships between these fields like this:

```
Movie AND Actor : Many To Many

Movie AND Director : Many To One

Movie AND IMDB : Many To One

Movie AND Genre : Many To Many
```

So now my question is, are these relationships correct or wrong ?

Comment: you are right, but movie and indm is 1:1

Comment: Is "the Coen Brothers" one director or two?